# Relationships between companions

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

Like in many RPG games, in the "POE2: Deadfire" you can build a relationship (either good or bad) between the PC and companions, which is neatly displayed on the characters screen. But to my surprise, companions have a similar screen showing how much they like/dislike another companion.

When I've hired Tekēhu, almost immediately he started annoying Aloth with his irresponsibility and Xoti with his sexist comments. Similarly, I've noticed that there won't be much love between priestess Xoti and antireligious Pallegina.

Do those animosities/friendships affect the game in any way? Is there a way to find who is most likely to like/dislike whom?

Answer (score 4):

I've been digging around the Internet and here's what I've found:

Indeed, if the relationship between two companions drops too low, they can issue ultimatum asking you to choose one of them.

Now, based on [this table](https://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Companion_relationship#Companion_topics) and a few posts on different forums I can guess that:

- Aloth doesn't like much anyone, but he is dutifull just like Maia and Pallegina. He will probably dislike Serafen and hate irresponsible Takehu.
- Eder should be easy: he should get along with most people, especially Xoti and maybe Maia. He might not share Takehu progressive views.
- Maia should like Aloth and probably Eder. She would dislike Pallegina (they work for different factions) and really not get along with Takehu
- Pallegina should like Aloth and besides that she's bit grumpy, not liking Maia, Takehu and Xoti
- Serafen should like Eder and Tekehu, there might be problems with Xoti and some political turmoil with Maia and Pallegina
- Takehu: Serafen should be his friend while most other would dislike him, especially Xoti, Maia and Aloth
- Xoti likes Edar and most other characters, except for Pallegina. She might dislike Serafen's methods and Takehu's irresponsibility